# Detecting Discord Mentions Without A Bot?

Tags: c#, windows, hook, discord

Im currently coding in C# to make my razer keyboard react to notifications, and other things. This is my first time using C# and I was wondering how I would detect discord notifications? Selfbots are agains't Discord rules, and other bots are not an option. One suggestion was I use a windows hook, however after searching around, it seems most everyone says you can't easily do this in C#. So I was wondering if there were any better ideas, and if not, how would I go about doing windows hooks?

EDIT: This is a WPF app.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your messageRecieved handler, you just need to add in a few more lines of code to check for mentions to your account (the client).

```
var mentionedUser = message.MentionedUsers;
        //Using a loop
        foreach(var user in mentionedUser) {
            if(user == client.CurrentUser) {
                //Do something
            }
        }

        //Or you could do it...
        if(message.Content.Contains("<@YOURID>")) {
            //Do something
        }
```

If you don't have a messageRecieved Handler yet, its a property from `DiscordSocketClient` object.
You can look at the documentation's tutorial on setting up event handlers for the client [here](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/getting_started/intro.html).

Alternatively, if you only want to trigger the code when the mention is only at the front (or somewhere specific) of the message, you can convert the `SocketMessage` given to a `SocketUserMessage`, then use the `HasMentionPrefix()` method in `SocketUserMessage`.
(Similar to how the documentation did for setting up CommandModules)

Comment: In case you didn't read the original post, I stated "Selfbots are against Discord rules" this means I cannot use a selfbot, nor the discord API.